# Остановка всех потоков по нажатию клавиши Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Имеется клавиша Start по нажатию которой запускается новый поток

```
startBalls.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        new BallThread(jpanel).start();
        counter++;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии клавиши Stop, происходила остановка всех потоков, с возможностью последующего запуска с того же места. Каким образом это лучше реализовать?

```
pauseBalls.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        ?????
    }
});
```

Comment: в теории.. вам нужно все созданные элементы сохранять скажем в коллекцию.. А потом циклом по ней пройтись и все элементы выключить. Это не относится именно к потокам, по ним не подскажу, не работал. Ну вроде метод `stop`

Comment: Вы же [уже спрашивали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786479/204271).

Comment: @MaxMarkich в таком случае при остановке необходимо возвращать состояние и при запуске снова инициализировать поток с помощью сохраненного состояния